# Call method through Arraylist of another class containing a HashMap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

So I'm taking a basic course in Java at university. I'm trying to create a class Bachelorstudents containing an arraylist of class Bachelorstudent (respectively plural and singular of "bachelorstudents" in english) which contains a HashMap of course (key) and marks (value).

My problem is the infamous "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context".

"Bachelorstudent"-class:

```
public class Bachelorstudent{
    private String navn;
    private int studentNummer;
    private HashMap<String, Integer> karakterListe = new HashMap<>();
    public Bachelorstudent(String navn, Integer studentNummer){
        setNavn(navn);
        setStudentNummer(studentNummer);
    }
    public Bachelorstudent(){
    }
    public void setKarakter(String fagkode, Integer karakter){
        karakterListe.put(fagkode, karakter);
    }

    public HashMap<String, Integer> getKarakter(){
        return karakterListe;
    }
    public int snitt(){
        Integer snittKarakter = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        if(!karakterListe.isEmpty()){
            for(Integer karakter : karakterListe.values()){
                snittKarakter += karakter;
                counter++;
            }
        }else{
            return 6;
        }
        return snittKarakter /= counter;
    }
    public int getKarakterer(){
        Integer karakterer = 0;
        if(!karakterListe.isEmpty()){
            for(Integer karakter : karakterListe.values()){
                karakterer += karakter;
            }
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
        return karakterer;
    }

    public void setNavn(String navn){
        this.navn=navn;
    }
    public String getNavn(){
        return navn;
    }
    public void setStudentNummer(int studentNummber){
        this.studentNummer=studentNummer;
    }
    public int getStudentNummer(){
        return studentNummer;
    }
}
```

"Bachelorstudenter"-class:

```
public class Bachelorstudenter{
    private ArrayList<Bachelorstudent> bachelorStudenter = new ArrayList<>();

    public Bachelorstudenter(){
    }
    public void karakterSnitt(){

        for(Bachelorstudent bachelorstudenter : bachelorStudenter){
            Bachelorstudent student = new Bachelorstudent();
            for(Bachelorstudent bachelorstudent : Bachelorstudent.getKarakter()){ //<-- Non-static method error.
            }
        }
    }

    public Boolean eksisterer(Bachelorstudent student){
        boolean finnes = false;
        for(Bachelorstudent bachelorstudent : bachelorStudenter){
            if(bachelorstudent.getNavn().equals(student.getNavn())){
                finnes = true;
                }
            }
        return finnes;
    }
    public Boolean nyBachelorstudent(Bachelorstudent student){
        if(!eksisterer(student)){
            bachelorStudenter.add(student);
            return true;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Eksisterer i systemet fra før");
            return false;

        }
    }
}
```

I have tried several things, such as calling an instance of class Bachelorstudent (as seen above), tried inheritance (not sure if I did this right, but what I did didn't work). How can I call on the .getKarakter() method in class Bachelorstudenter?

Edit: Just to clarify. The point of this method is to get the average of every mark of every bachelorstudent. I have a method in Bachelorstudent which does this, but I need the equivalent in Bachelorstudenter, which will find the average of every mark of every course of every student.

Comment: You are calling `Bachelorstudent.karakterer();` without an object. I think you meant to write`bachelorstudent.karakterer();` (lower-case 'b').  Also `karakterer` is not a method on `Bachelorstudent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an object to call a non-static method.

In your example, you need to use the object of the current iteration to invoke the method:

```
for(Bachelorstudent bachelorstudenter : bachelorStudenter){ // Iterate over the bachelorStudenter list.
    bachelorstudenter.getKarakter(); // Use the bachelorstudenter of this iteration.
}
```